# Google Cloud Load Balancer : ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-load-balancer

Hi I have a domain name which is registered with https://www.networksolutions.com/. I have added nameservers which were mentioned in the Cloud DNS when I created zone.

After this I added SSL certificate which Google provides,

[image]

after this I added several subdomains and mapped this external IP of the load balancer to those domain names in the Cloud DNS section.

But even after doing all these steps when I am trying to access my website using https it given me following error.

[image]

Following are my domain names,
[image]

Here is my frontend configuration for http(working fine) and https,

**HTTP Load Balancer Frontend:**

[image]

**HTTPS Load Balancer Frontend:**
[image]

In my domain name provider's setting I have added following nameservers,

**Nameservers :**

[image]
Is there any other configuration which needs to be added or changed ?

Comment: Usually any DNS changes you make need time to propagate over the Internet (even up to 24 hours). If you change the TTL time in your dns zone records you will speed up this process to whatever you need. If you want the domain to propagate fast just set 60 seconds and wait a little bit. This will still take some time (a couple of minutes usually).

Comment: Its been nearly 2 days I have added domain names and ssl certificate. Still the same error.

Comment: For problems like this, include your domain name. We can then rapidly determine what is wrong instead of guessing.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added screenshot of domain names. Please have a look.

Comment: **foo-test.ordazzle.net** resolves to 34.149.36.208. Your problem appears to be the custom domain name assigned to the load balancer. Either the name is not configured or incorrectly configured. Edit your question and include the front-end configuration for both HTTP and HTTPS. Include the values for the DNS records, you only show the names. Your domain also appears to only have one Name Server configured. Google provides four Name Servers. I recommend reading an article or two on the basics of DNS.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your valuable feedback. I have edited the question with asked configurations. Could you please have a look. and  Sure I will learn more about these things :).

Comment: You have one big problem. You are using different global IP addresses for HTTP and HTTPS. Delete the HTTPS frontend and recreate using the same IP address as the HTTP frontend. However, that is only one of your problems. I am not sure yet what the primary problem is. Neither HTTP nor HTTPS are working.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the suggestion. I have Made required changes. Now http://foo-test.ordazzle.net/ this is working as expected but https://foo-test.ordazzle.net/ still giving the error.  could you please suggest any other way out on this ?

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried with self signed certificate and its working now. I think something was wrong with google's ssl certificate configuration. just fyu i used this command. sudo openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt

Comment: Where did you install the self-signed certificate? If you installed it at that load balancer front-end, web browsers will report errors/problems. There is no problem with Google's SSL certificate generation. You probably created it incorrectly. Details matter, please be very specific with each item.